# Solving Coupled system of differential equation with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am solving a system with coupled system of differential equation to obtain the time evolution of two vectors. The problem stated here is equivalent to solving Landau Lifschitz Gilbert equation[LLG Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Lifshitz%E2%80%93Gilbert_equation) for two systems with a coupling between them. 
In my problem, m1[t] and m2[t] are two 3 component column vectors in cartesian coordinates. m1[t]={m1x,m1y,m1z} and m2[t]={m2x,m2y,m2z} respectively. m1[t] and m2[t] are acted upon by a term called effective field (HAnis).This HAnis is derived from an energy term

```
EAnis[r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]] := (K1*(Sin[\[Theta]]^2) + 
           K2*(Sin[\[Theta]]^4) + K3*(Sin[\[Theta]]^6)*(Cos[6 \[CurlyPhi]]));
HAnis = Simplify[
   r*Grad[EAnis[r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]], {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]},
      "Spherical"]]/MS;
```

Theta and phi are the polar and azimuthal angles in a spherical polar coordinate geometry. The time derivative of m1[t] and m2[t] is given by

```
cons1[t_] := -gamma*(10^(-9))*(-Hexch*Cross[m1[t], m2[t]] + 
     Cross[m1[t], (HAnis + Hext)]);
tGilbdamp1[t_] := alphag*Cross[m1[t], cons1[t]];
LLGS1 = {m1'[t] == cons1[t] + tGilbdamp1[t], 
   m1[0] == ToSphericalCoordinates[{1, 0, 0}]};
```

and

```
cons2[t_] := -gamma*(10^(-9))*(-Hexch*Cross[m2[t], m1[t]] + 
     Cross[m2[t], (HAnis + Hext)]);
tGilbdamp2[t_] := alphag*Cross[m2[t], cons2[t]];
LLGS2 = {m2'[t] == cons2[t] + tGilbdamp2[t], 
   m2[0] == ToSphericalCoordinates[{-1, 0, 0}]};
```

I tried to obtain numerical solution by

```
    sol1 = NDSolve[{LLGS1, LLGS2}, {m1, m2}, {t, tStart, tFinish}, 
   StartingStepSize -> tStep, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", 
     Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 10, PrecisionGoal -> 100, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]];
```

And I have stumbled upon the following error messages.

```
Cross::nonn1: The arguments are expected to be vectors of equal length, and the number of arguments is expected to be 1 less than their length.

Cross::nonn1: The arguments are expected to be vectors of equal length, and the number of arguments is expected to be 1 less than their length.

Cross::nonn1: The arguments are expected to be vectors of equal length, and the number of arguments is expected to be 1 less than their length.

General::stop: Further output of Cross::nonn1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. The constants in the above equations are as follows:

```
gamma = 1.760859*(10^11);
alphag = (10^(-4));
tStep = (10^(-3));
tStart = 0;
tFinish = 8;
K1 = (3*(10^5));
K2 = (5*(10^5));
K3 = (5*(10^5));
Hext = {0, 0, 0};
Hexch = 1000;
MS = 238732.41;
```

Comment: Please give all necessary information to run your code. For now, `Hexch`, `Hext`, and `tSlondamp2[t]` are undefined. Also, sometimes you use `m1` and `m2` without explicit time-dependence (`m1[t]` and `m2[t]`).

Comment: Sorry @Roman. Thanks for your reply. tSlondamp[t] can be discarded for now and I have updated the code in the post. The values of Hexch (scalar) and Hext (3 component coloumn vector) are also updated. Hexch = 1000 and Hext = {0,0,0}. m1 and m2 are time dependent vectors.

Comment: I think you're mixing up Cartesian and spherical coordinates. `ToSphericalCoordinates[{1, 0, 0}]` gives spherical coordinates, but you equate it to `m1[0]` which you say is in Cartesian coordinates. Same for `Hanis` being in spherical coordinates but then appears in a `Cross` product with `m1[t]` (in the definition of `cons1`). As the code stands I think it cannot work, even if you fix the error messages.

Answer (score 3):

If we correct all typos and add data for $\theta, \phi$, then the code works

```
gamma = 1.760859*10^11; 
alphag = 10^(-4); 
tStep = 10^(-3); 
tStart = 0; 
tFinish = 8; 
K1 = 3*10^5; 
K2 = 5*10^5; 
K3 = 5*10^5; 
Hext = {0, 0, 0}; 
Hexch = 1000; 
MS = 238732.41; EAnis[r_, \[Theta]_, \[CurlyPhi]_] := K1*Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + K2*Sin[\[Theta]]^4 + K3*Sin[\[Theta]]^6*Cos[6*\[CurlyPhi]]; 
HAnis = Simplify[r*Grad[EAnis[r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]], {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]}, "Spherical"]]/MS; 
cons1[t_] := ((-gamma)*((-Hexch)*Cross[m1[t], m2[t]] + Cross[m1[t], HAnis + Hext]))/10^9; 
tGilbdamp1[t_] := alphag*Cross[m1[t], cons1[t]]; 
LLGS1 = {Derivative[1][m1][t] == cons1[t] + tGilbdamp1[t], m1[0] == ToSphericalCoordinates[{1, 0, 0}]}; 
cons2[t_] := ((-gamma)*((-Hexch)*Cross[m2[t], m1[t]] + Cross[m2[t], HAnis + Hext]))/10^9; 
tGilbdamp2[t_] := alphag*Cross[m2[t], cons2[t]]; 
LLGS2 = {Derivative[1][m2][t] == cons2[t] + tGilbdamp2[t], m2[0] == ToSphericalCoordinates[{-1, 0, 0}]}; 
sol1 = NDSolve[{LLGS1, 
    LLGS2} /. {\[Theta] -> 1, \[CurlyPhi] -> 0}, {m1, m2}, {t, tStart,
    tFinish}]

Plot[m1[t] /. sol1, {t, tStart, tFinish}]

Plot[m2[t] /. sol1, {t, tStart, tFinish}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: As I wrote above, this code mixed Cartesian and spherical coordinates erratically. Now it runs, yes; but the output is probably useless.

Comment: @Roman We are fixing code errors here. Errors model let the author fixes himself.

Comment: Yes Alex I agree.

Comment: @Alex and Roman Thanks for your help. I have tried in a different way. I wrote m1 and m2 in cartesian co-ordinates. Used spherical polar derivatives for E and performed orthogonal basis transformation to convert them into cartesian coordinates. And then applied used ND Solve to obtain a solution.

Comment: @Matcax What does this have to do with the Landau-Lifschitz-Gilbert model?